# Fetching data from CSV file locally, iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, search, csv, uitextfield

I am developing an iphone app which will fetch the data from CSV file as per the keyword entered in to the UITextFiled, eg. if user enters london than all the possible entries containing the same keyword should be listed down, I have tried CHCSVParser but i am still not able to conclude any result. Can anyone tell me is it even feasible??? and if yes than please help me through the initial steps. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, then using a plist instead of csv will be much easier/flexible.

Comment: but the file i am fetching data from comprises 15000+ entries, would it be feasible for plist?

Comment: With 15000 entries you'd be better of using a local sql lite database and neither plist nor csv.

Comment: Here's the first tutorial I found : http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: i thought so but could not find any way to convert csv in to sqlite. So stuck at this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can import your data in a .sqlite ressource file that contains all elements from your csv file.

Then for listing 15 000 elements or a subset of them in a tableview, the nsfetchedresultscontroller will help you. Initializing it with a fetch request will permits you to filter your elements based on one or more attribute name(s).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you're going to repeatedly reference "random" elements of your CSV file, you should convert it to an SQLite DB (though that would be overkill if you're only referencing things once).  For your app, as well as I can understand the description, a DB of some sort is most definitely warranted.

As to reading the CSV file, there are, no doubt, tools available, but it's probably just as easy to use NSString `componentsSeparatedByString` to parse each line.